# How to write Pytorch Dataset class and DataLoader for a multi-output regression problem?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, regression, dataloader

I am working with event-based data (consisting of timestamps, x and y coordinates, and polarity) on a neuromorphic problem. However, my question is how do I create the Dataset and proper DataLoader when I am trying to predict multiple outputs? Specifically, I am trying to predict the x-component, y-component, and z-component of a velocity vector. This is what my current custom Dataset class looks like:

```
import os
import ast
import torch
import tonic
import torchvision
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import tonic.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class SyntheticRecording(tonic.Dataset):
    """
        Synthetic event camera recordings dataset.
    """
    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        super(SyntheticRecording, self).__init__()
        self.csv_file = csv_file
        df = pd.read_csv(self.csv_file, index_col = False)
        self.events = df['Events'] # Select only last column of dataframe
        self.target = df[['Vel_x', 'Vel_y', 'Vel_z']] # Select every column except last column of dataframe
        assert(self.target.shape[0] == len(self.events))
        self.sensor_size = (1920, 1080, 2)
    
    """
        Retrieve the index i to get the ith sample from the dataset. Apply the appropriate transformations.
    """
    def __getitem__(self, index):
      list_ = ast.literal_eval(self.events[index])
      t = []
      x = []
      y = []
      p = []
      for e in list_:
        t.append(e[0] * 1e6) # Convert to microseconds
        x.append(e[1])
        y.append(e[2])
        p.append(e[3])
      events = tonic.io.make_structured_array(x, y, t, p) # Ordering is xytp now
      
      # Denoise removes isolated, one-off events
      frame_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Denoise(filter_time = 10000), 
                                            transforms.ToFrame(sensor_size = self.sensor_size, 
                                                         time_window = 1000)
                                            ])
      transformed_frames = frame_transform(events)
      vel_x = np.array(self.target.loc[index][0]).astype('float')
      vel_y = np.array(self.target.loc[index][1]).astype('float')
      vel_z = np.array(self.target.loc[index][2]).astype('float')
      
      sample = {'frames': transformed_frames,
                'vel_x': vel_x,
                'vel_y': vel_y,
                'vel_z': vel_z}

      return sample
```

This is how I try to create the DataLoader:

```
batch_size = 16
trainloader = DataLoader(sr, batch_size = batch_size, collate_fn = tonic.collation.PadTensors(), shuffle = True, drop_last = True)
```

Whenever I try to iterate over the frames and target values (3 values), I receive the following error:

```
for frames, targets in trainloader:
  print(frames.shape)
  print(targets.shape)
```

```
frames, targets = next(iter(trainloader))
```

results in: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

What is the right way to create a DataLoader that can handle a multi-prediction regression problem?

EDIT:

I am using this as my resource to try to handle the multi output part: https://medium.com/jdsc-tech-blog/multioutput-cnn-in-pytorch-c5f702d4915f

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
for sample in trainloader:
   print(sample)
```

In this way you can check how many values are being returned in the output printed.

Comment: I tried to implement this with the same setup as above and got the following error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I also stumbled on the same issue and here is how I fixed it:

The problem is not in iterating over the dataloader, but it is from the `collate_fn` you pass to the `DataLoader` as it assumes that your target is only 1 value. The error you get is from tonic's [PadTensor()](https://tonic.readthedocs.io/en/main/_modules/tonic/collation.html?highlight=PadTensors#) function where it iterates over the new batches:

```
for sample, target in batch:
    ...
```

It assumes that you don't have a dictionary but a tuple that can be unpacked. Later it then assumes that the target is also just one value.

## How to fix

1. **Modify the collate function:**

Create a new class where you remove the assumption of the target being just one value, like this:

```
class MultiTargetPadTensors:
    def __init__(self, batch_first: bool = True):
        self.batch_first = batch_first

    def __call__(self, batch):
        samples_output = []
        targets_output = []

        max_length = max([sample.shape[0] for sample, target in batch])

        for sample, target in batch:
            if not isinstance(sample, torch.Tensor):
                sample = torch.tensor(sample)

            sample = torch.cat(
                (
                    sample,
                    torch.zeros(
                        max_length - sample.shape[0],
                        *sample.shape[1:],
                        device=sample.device
                    ),
                )
            )
            samples_output.append(sample)
            targets_output.append(target)
        
        samples_output = torch.stack(samples_output, 0 if self.batch_first else 1)
        targets_output = ??? # TODO: Stack the targets according to your use case
        return (samples_output, targets_output)
```

The DataLoader should now look like this: `DataLoader(sr, batch_size = batch_size, collate_fn = MultiTargetPadTensors(), shuffle = True, drop_last = True)`

2. **Adjust the Dataset:**

Instead of a dictionary, return a tuple like this:

```
    ...
    sample = (transformed_frames, [vel_x, vel_y, vel_z])
    return sample
```